# Is it possible to record audio using Apple Watch in background (screen off)?

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, watch, watchos

The question subject is in title. I can’t find any signs related to audio background modes in watchOS. However, Apple declared

> Use new background modes for navigation and audio recording.

On promotional watchOS 4 page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was struggling with this same thing, there really isn't good documentation on this at the moment.

It turns out you just need to add the background audio key (as you would in an iOS app). Add the following to your watch extension's `info.plist` file:

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>audio</string>
</array>
```

Also make sure you are setting the current audio session to a category that supports audio recording.